# PayPal sandbox button goes to My Account Summary

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Here's my problem. I've tried being logged into my Developer Account with PayPal, but every time I test the button I made in Sandbox I just get redirected as follows and can't complete the test transaction:

1. Using my details (obviously I've replaced my details with fake ones here).

[image]

2. I go to my test site and click on the button I created in Sandbox mode:

[image]

3. Which takes me here. I use the buyer sandbox email to login.

[image]

4. Then, no matter what I do, I end up here with an incomplete transaction.

[image]

I've been going around in circles, clearing caches, cookies, going incognito but can't make it work! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We had a known issue at PayPal's end which is causing this issue. The engineering team is working on this issue for a fix. No ETA at the moment. Will update here once the issue gets fixed.